# How do I optimize a rotation of the roots of unity?

Tags: optimization, roots-of-unity, gradient-descent

Any rotation of the $m$th roots of unity is a finite normalized tight frame (FNTF) of $\mathbb{R}^2$. According to [Benedetto and Fickus](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiayvrittLpAhWDc98KHX1yBo0QFjAAegQIBhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Fpublication%2F220390877_Finite_Normalized_Tight_Frames&usg=AOvVaw2xcoJLCwiNwlumBfK3ud20), every  minimizer $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^{m}$  of the "frame potential" $$FP(\{x_i\}_{i=1}^{m}) = \sum_{i,j=1}^m |\langle x_i, x_j \rangle|^2$$
is a FNTF of $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Given a random initial set $\{x^{(0)}_i\}_{i=1}^{m}$, I would like to produce some rotation of the roots of unity by minimizing $FP$ via gradient descent in the case of $d=2$.

However, when I numerically minimize the (hopefully transparent) function

```
def FP(phases):
phase_diffs = phases - phases.transpose(1,0)
return (torch.abs(torch.cos(phase_diffs))**2).sum()
```

where `phases` are the angles of $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^{3}$ measured counter-clockwise from the x-axis, I see

[image]

which are evidently not roots of unity.

Have I misunderstood the frame potential or is this an optimization problem or both? I can provide more details about the solver if necessary.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you plug in the m-th roots of unity into your FP function, what do you get? To make sure there are no errors in the programming vs the math.

Comment: The m-th roots definitely minimize the FP function, but the example I posted _also_ achieves the minimal value of the frame potential for m=3, d=2 (4.5). So perhaps FP is coded incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

$$
FP (\{ x_i \}_{i=1}^m) = \sum_{i,j=1}^m \mid \langle x_i , x_j \rangle \mid^2\\
$$

Let $\alpha_i$ be $\pm 1$ chosen independently.

$$
FP (\{ \alpha_i x_i \}_{i=1}^m) = \sum_{i,j=1}^m \mid \langle \alpha_i x_i , \alpha_j x_j \rangle \mid^2\\
= \sum_{i,j=1}^m \mid \alpha_i \alpha_j \langle x_i , x_j \rangle \mid^2\\
= \sum_{i,j=1}^m \mid \langle x_i , x_j \rangle \mid^2\\
= FP (\{ x_i \}_{i=1}^m)
$$

So you see that the solution you got starts with the third roots of unity, but then messes with the signs by $\alpha_1=-1$ and $\alpha_2=\alpha_3=+1$.

When you minimize FP, you don't know a priori what these signs are.

Comment: Ah, yes. You can see this from the plot I posted. Thank  you for pointing this out!

By the way, a more reliable potential is hinted at in this paper, if you are interested: 

https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2308976.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3Aa738ebf0d4e9ec5d40878d7d54406f23